# Why does my express Node.js app published to an Azure App Service throw and internal server error in the browser?

Tags: node.js, express, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am attempting my first deployment of a Node.js web app to an Azure App Service.
I am publishing through VS 2019 and it looks like it's publishing correctly.

I am able publish using the standard server.js code snippet that comes with default project creation. In a browser I see the correct Azure URL and "Hello World" displays correctly.

**Here is the default code snippet:**

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

I'm trying to create a simple WebService API using express.

**Here is the code snippet for that:**

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('root:: Azure Express Web Server Successful!');
});


server.listen(4242, () => {
    console.log('Express Test is Running...');
});
```

I've added the express package through VS 2019 to the project so it does show up in my list of npm packages and in my packages.json file:

```
{
  "name": "foo-bar",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "FooBar",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "~6.10.x"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2",
  }
}
```

It appears to publish successfully to my Azure App Service (Windows).
However when I hit the URL in a browser (Chrome), I get the following error message:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
> occurred.

This is a simple Node.js app that runs correctly locally thru VS 2019 and command line.
Is there something wrong with my code module or package definition?
Am I missing a step for correctly publish the npm dependency?
How do I trace this error down?
Should I be using the Express template?

From Azure - Application Performance Analyzer - Failed Requests, I see the following error information:

Method  Request Path    Duration    Failing Module  Failure Status  Final Status    Details
GET /   51.28 sec   iisnode 500.1001    200.0
GET /   51.46 sec   iisnode 500.1001    200.0
Request Details
Requesthttp://WebServerTest20220214013438:80/
RequestId8000032f-0000-e700-b63f-84710c7967bbReasonInternal Server Error
HTTP Status200.0CS-Bytes1447SC-Bytes452
Total Time Spent51,284 msError Code0ModuleNameiisnodeNotificationExecuteRequestHandler

Comment: Surely there's a log viewer in the azure dashboard that would tell you what's happening.

Comment: New to Azure, trying to figure this out. Looked at Activity Log for this service and didn't see anything there. Surely this must be a difference between configuring/using express on Azure vs locally. New to Node.js, but don't see anything obvious in source snippet or packages.json file.